# Randomized Grouping Jquery

Tags: jquery, random, grouping

I decided that my previous question wasnt perhaps clear in both title and result, so I decided to ask the question like this...

I have 3 categories (A,B,C) and in these categories i have 3 items each. So category A)dog,cat,mouse B)apple,cherry,banana C)red,green,yellow.

I was wondering if its possible to group these items from the categories at random. So for example each time you click on the same button it would group: dog,apple,yellow or cat,cherry,green or mouse,apple,red , etc... and adds the class .grouped or whatever to that group. with only one possible group at a time with three items.

so i guess it would be like from start

```
class="dog"
class="cat"
class="mouse"
class="apple"
class="cherry"
class="banana"
class="red"
class="green"
class="yellow"
```

and then you click button & get:

```
class="dog grouped"
class="apple grouped"
class="yellow grouped"
```

click button again & get

```
class="cat grouped"
class="cherry grouped"
class="green grouped"
```

any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated

-david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible as you can see below. There are definitely more elegant ways to do this, but I figured this would be pretty straight forward to understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/EN7HQ/1/

**JS**

```
var groupA = ["dog","cat","mouse"],
    groupB = ["apple", "cherry","bannana"],
    groupC = ["red","green","yellow"];

$("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#groups").children().remove();
    var itemA = groupA[Math.round(Math.random()*2)],
        itemB = groupB[Math.round(Math.random()*2)],
        itemC = groupC[Math.round(Math.random()*2)];

    $("#groups").append("<div class='" + itemA + " grouped'>" + itemA + "</div>"); 
    $("#groups").append("<div class='" + itemB + " grouped'>" + itemB + "</div>"); 
    $("#groups").append("<div class='" + itemC + " grouped'>" + itemC + "</div>"); 
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="clickme">Click Me</div>
<div id="groups">
</div>
```

Comment: thats awesome thanks!, quick question what does the .children. remove do in this situation?

Comment: it removes the previously added elements to the `<div id='groups'></div>`

Answer (score 1):

This will probably get you going. For the html:

```
<span class="animal">dog</span>
<span class="animal">cat</span>
<span class="animal">mouse</span>
<span class="fruit">apple</span>
<span class="fruit">cherry</span>
<span class="fruit">banana</span>
<span class="colour">red</span>
<span class="colour">green</span>
<span class="colour">yellow</span>
```

Then this javascript will randomly add the class

```
function regroup() {
  //remove existing
  $(".grouped").removeClass("grouped");

  //the random Math.floor is just to generate a random number
  $(".animal:eq(" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)) + ")").addClass("grouped");
  $(".fruit:eq(" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)) + ")").addClass("grouped");
  $(".colour:eq(" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)) + ")").addClass("grouped");
}
```

The idea is to generate a random number within the number of each class, and then add the class to it.

Comment: +1 I didn't see this last night, good approach if you are using already created elements.